# Unity отсчет времени

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно реализовать отсчет времени в игре через DateTime? Что бы допустим через 24 какое то действие выполнилось

Пытался так, не отсчитывает

```
System.DateTime currentFirstStartupDate = System.DateTime.Today;

        if ((currentFirstStartupDate - System.DateTime.Now).Seconds == 10f)
        {
            Debug.Log ("is Work");

        }
```

Comment: `DateTime` - это просто дата и время. Не знаю, как в Unity, но в обычном приложении это делается таймерами или циклом, который постоянно проверяет сколько времени прошло с момента запуска.

Comment: можете показать примерную реализацию с таймером?

Comment: Смысл? Вам же для юнити надо - ищите таймеры в юнити.

Comment: if(timer<=0f) {timer=84600f; ...} else timer-=Time.deltaTime;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот реализация таймера который просто опускается вниз до нуля.

```
//точность до секунды
IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(float timeInSec)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeInSec);
     //сделать нужное
}
```

или так:

```
//точность до милисекунды
function Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    if ( timeLeft < 0 )
    {
        //что-то сделать по окончанию времени
    }
}
```

Если же нужно каждые N секунд делать что-то, то

```
//точность до милисекунды
private float nextActionTime = 0.0f;
public float period = 0.1f;

void Update () {
    if (Time.time > nextActionTime ) {
    nextActionTime += period;
    // execute block of code here
    }
}
```

или так:

```
//точность до секунды
IEnumerator DoCheck() {
     for(;;) {
         //что-то сделать каждые  time секунд
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
     }
}
```

ну и запуск последнего блока кода:

```
StartCoroutine("DoCheck");
```

Comment: `for(;;)` смотрится, несомненно, эффектнее, чем `while(true)` :)

Answer (score 1):

Таймер:

```
public float timer;

Void Update() {
  if(timer > 0) timer -= Time.DeltaTime;
  if(timer < 0) timer = 0; 
}
```

Секундомер:

```
public float secundomer;
Void Update() {
  if(secundomer < 10) secundomer += Time.DeltaTime;
  if(secundomer > 10) secundomer = 0; 
}
```

Также можно использовать карутину.

Comment: В обоих случаях можно обойтись одной проверкой, а не двумя. Да и про корутину, раз уж вы про неё вспомнили, стоит написать.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как вы считаете, но можно попробовать так:

```
public float Time;
Void Update(){
  Time = Time + Time.deltaTime;
  if (Time = 5) {
    //you code
  }
}
```

или что-то в этом роде