# Как сделать таймер с циклом в 30 секунд?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Всем привет.
Как сделать таймер с циклом в 30 секунд, то есть таймер который при достижении 0 секунд будет включаться снова?
Есть такой код

```
public float timeStart = 30;
public Text timerText;

void Start()
{
    timerText.text = timeStart.ToString();
}


void Update()
{     
        timeStart -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = Mathf.Round(timeStart).ToString();   
}
```

В общем получился вот такой говнокод, но он рабочий :D

```
public float timeStart = 30f;
public Text timerText;

void Start()
{
    timerText.text = timeStart.ToString();
}


void Update()
{     
    timeStart -= Time.deltaTime;
    timerText.text = Mathf.Round(timeStart).ToString();  
    if ( timeStart <= 0f)
    {
        timeStart = 30f;
        timeStart -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = Mathf.Round(timeStart).ToString();
    }
}
```

С удовольствием приму критику и учту ошибки:)

Comment: ИМХО, самый лучший таймер - `while(true){ //логика await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))}`.

Comment: К сожалению я ещё новичек в программировании, если вам не трудно можно расписать код?

Comment: Я вам весь код дал)

Comment: Хорошо, разберусь, спасибо!)

Comment: [вот такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fkbpfl) я имел ввиду, это прям самое базовое и элементарное, которое в многих случаешь подходит прям очень хорошо. Ну а так, везде есть свои механизмы, в том же Unity они также присутствуют, например [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/891515/220553).

Comment: Решение лучше публиковать в ответ, если оно вас устраивает, отдельным постом ниже. А из вопроса - убрать. Но да, метод `Update()` вполне подходит для таких штук.

Answer (score 0):

Для действий, которые не зависят от обновления кадров, а работают по времени исользуют корутины. Мое описание дурацкое, лучше почитайте в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Coroutines.html). Очень коротко, корутина - это функция, которая не обязана выполнится за 1 кадр, в котором она была вызвана.

Корутина может *подождать* некоторое количество секунд с помощью строки:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(float time); // time - время
```

*Подождать* она может даже несколько раз, т.е. то, что в этой строке есть слово return не значит, что функция после этого завершится.

Допустим, вы хотите, чтобы через 5 секунд после запуска приложения вывело `Goodbye World` 3 раза, между которыми пройдет по 3 секунды.

> `Goodbye World` - Неожиданно, не правда ли?

```
private void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(writePhrase()); // Обратите внимание, что корутина зупскается по-особенному, с помощью StartCoroutine()
}
private IEnumerator writePhrase () {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // Начальная задержка
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        print("Goodbye World"); // Вывод
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); // Задержка между фразами
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что хотя корутина и будет ждать, тот код, откуда она была вызвана продолжится и закончит выполнение в этом же кадре. Например, если мы в предыдущей программе в методе Start() перед вызовом корутины добавим строчку `print("BEFORE");`, а после вызова корутины строчку `print("AFTER");` То вывод будет выглядеть как:

- BEFORE
- AFTER
- Goodbye World
- Goodbye World
- Goodbye World

То есть Start() продолжил выполнение, несмотря на то, что вызванная им корутина еще не закончила выполнение и ждала.

Помимо WaitForSeconds(), который ждет X секунд, есть, например, WaitForEndOfFrame(), который ждет до конца кадр и др.

> Вы могли бы это прочитать в документации (и до сих пор можете), но я вам расписал понятнее и простым языком. Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, примите его, поставив галочку.